# Copy specific column in excel to new sheet using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select and copy specific entire column from one sheet to another however not able to do it ,below is the code:

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G1").Value
```

any idea how we can set the entire column range?

Answer (score 1):

To copy entire column, instead of

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G1").Value
```

write

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B:B").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G:G").Value
```

and to retain the number format write-

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("B").NumberFormat = "General"
```

**__________________________________________________________________________**

You can even use `Column` as:

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("B").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("G").Value
```

**__________________________________________________________________________**

You can also use `Copy` as:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("G").Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("B")
```

Comment: Thanks Mrig..I have a value however while doing it ,it's getting change to date format.any idea how to retain the value ?

Comment: @Harshit - It's because your `Column B` in `Sheet3` might be formatted as `Date`. Use `Copy` as `Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("G").Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("B")`

Answer (score 0):

You can either

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("G").copy Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("B")
```

or

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("B") = Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("G").Value
```

If you want to copy multiple columns that are connected you can do

```
Sheets("sheet2").Columns("G:H").copy sheets("Sheet3").Columns("B:C")
```

for Keeping it as general format, you can add

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("G").NumberFormat = "General"
```